# Difference in syntax and time complexity for C# for loop

Tags: c#, optimization, .net-core

I am trying to figure out what the difference between the following for loops is.

The first is code that I wrote while practicing algorithms on codewars.com. It times out when attempting the larger test cases.

The second is one of the top solutions. It seems functionally similar (obviously its more concise) but runs much faster and does not time out. Can anyone explain to me what the difference is? Also, the return statement in the second snippet is confusing to me. What exactly does this syntax mean? Maybe this is where it is more efficient.

```
public static long findNb(long m)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    int x = new int();
    for (int n = 0; sum < m; n++)
    {
        sum += n*n*n;
        x = n;
        System.Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    if (sum == m)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

vs

```
public static long findNb(long m) //seems similar but doesnt time out
{
    long total = 1, i = 2;
    for(; total < m; i++) total += i * i * i;
    return total == m ? i - 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Could be that `System.Console.Writeline` call.  That's a lot of work for such a tight loop.

Comment: Try it with and without the `Writeline`

Comment: `total == m ? i - 1 : -1` is called a ternary operator. If the condition `total == m` is `true` then `i - 1` is evaluated, otherwise `-1`. The evaluated expression is then returned

Comment: Without knowing the value of `m` it's difficult to say, but I'd agree that it's most likely the `Console.Writeline` calls.

Comment: remove the console write line and x then your code is equivalent to the other one. You can keep one or the other to figure out what makes your code slow; I do agree with the previous comments that console write line is most likely the issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Console.Writeline was actually excluded from the code when it ran. For some reason even without Console.Writeline, it is still timing out.

Comment: Your loop does 2 iterations more than the proposed solution, but that shouldn't make a significant difference in terms of execution time. You have also an extra assignment that you can remove, x=n and do return n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach uses `long` for the total value. Chances are that you're using an `m` value that's high enough to exceed the number of values representable by `int`. So your math overflows and the `n` value becomes a negative number. You get caught in an infinite loop, where `n` can never get as big as `m`.

And, like everyone else says, get rid of the WriteLine.

> Also, the return statement in the second snippet is confusing to me. What exactly does this syntax mean?

It's a [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Comment: int vs long was the problem. the test was trying some trillion or quadrillion order of mag that was too big for int. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are roughly the *same*, except unwanted `System.Console.WriteLine(x);` which spolis the fun: printing on the `Console` (`UI`!) is a slow operation.

If you are looking for a *fast solution* (esp. for the large `m` and *long loop*) you can just *precompute* all (`77936`) values:

```
 public class Solver {
   static Dictionary<long, long> s_Sums = new Dictionary<long, long>();

   private static void Build() {
     long total = 0;

     for (long i = 0; i <= 77936; ++i) {
       total += i * i * i;

       s_Sums.Add(total, i);
     }
   } 

   static Solver() 
     Build(); 
   }

   public static long findNb(long m) {
     return s_Sums.TryGetValue(m, out long result) 
       ? result 
       : -1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. Console.Writeline was actually excluded from the code when it ran. For some reason even without Console.Writeline, it is still timing out.

Answer (score 2):

When I run into micro optimisation challenges like this, I always use [BenchmarkDotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org). It's the tool to use to get all the insights to performance, memory allocations, deviations in .NET Framework versions, 64bit vs 32 bit etc. etc.

But as others write - remember to remove the **WriteLine()** statement :)